# How to assign response to variable in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

If someone can help me understand how to bind response to view in angular4, i was just trying to get data from backend using `SteamService`  i have retrieve and printed the data now trying to assign it to `dataSource` using export interface but it is not happening. what is implemented wrong in below code ?

stream.component.html

```
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketNum">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ticket Number </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ticketNum}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="assetID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Asset ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.assetID}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="severity">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Severity </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.severity}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Color Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="riskIndex">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Risk Index </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.riskIndex}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="riskValue">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Risk Value </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.riskValue}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketOpened">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ticket Opened </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ticketOpened}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastModifiedDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Modified </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastModifiedDate}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="eventType">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Event Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.eventType}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

stream.module.ts

```
 import {
     Component,
     OnInit
 } from '@angular/core';
 import {
     StreamService
 } from '../stream.service';
 import {
     MatTableDataSource
 } from '@angular/material';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app-stream',
     templateUrl: './stream.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./stream.component.css']
 })
 export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
     displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
     dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
     stream: any[];
     constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {};
     ngOnInit() {
         this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
             this.stream = stream;
             const ELEMENT_DATA = Element[] = stream;
         });
     }

 }


 export interface Element {
     ticketNum: number;
     ticketOpened: number;
     eventType: string;
     riskIndex: string;
     riskValue: number;
     severity: string;
     lastModifiedDate: number;
     assetID: string;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show how you show your stream in HTML. cause it's an Async call. You use a | Async pipe then. So I have no clue if you use it.

Comment: i have added stream html to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `dataSource` is referring to `ELEMENT_DATA` which is not defined when `dataSource` is defined.

The definition of `ELEMENT_DATA` occurs in the callback of `subscribe` and it is scoped to this callback.

To make your assignment, you have to use `dataSource` inside the callback of `subscribe`.

Also, your `stream` is useless unless you use it elsewhere in the component.

You can write your code like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-stream',
    templateUrl: './stream.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stream.component.css']
})
export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Element[]>;

    constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(stream);
        });
    }
}


export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

Another way, you can make it is declaring `dataSource` like this:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element[]>();
```

And setting data like this:

```
this.dataSource.data(stream);
```

Comment: Dont we need to assign it to `Element` ? also with your code i see this error ` error TS2314: Generic type 'MatTableDataSource<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
`

Comment: I corrected the answer to take in account the `generic` in `MatTableDataSource`. There's no need to use `Element`, because it's in the type definition of `dataSource`. Also, it's only a `compile-time check` that `typescript` makes. In ànular` (and `typescript`) there's no check on runtime.

Comment: Perfect! this is all new to me coming from angular 1.3 any good tutorial you recommend to understand basics of ts ? Thank you so much for the help and thanks to stackoverflow to keep up this community.

Comment: You're welcome. You can do the `Hero tour` tutorial from `angular.io` site and read the documentation from `typescriptlang.org`. It's enough well made to understand it.

Comment: if any data element come from backend that is not part of `Element` interface it will break the application ? that might be separate question

Comment: Since, there's no `runtime` check of the data, if your backend sends data that does not fit the `Element` interface, it will generate errors.